# C# pointers. Memory clearing

Tags: c#, pointers

I have the following code:

```
protected int[] MEMORY;

private unsafe void GetPointer(string elemName, int* ptr)
{
    string tmp;
    if (elemName.Contains('['))
    {
        tmp = elemName.Remove('[').Remove(']');
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(tmp);
        fixed (int* array = MEMORY)
        {
             ptr = array + index;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Should I free up memory allocated for "array" variable in fixed block after I made operation "ptr = array + index" ?

Comment: I don't see any memory being allocated unless you mean for the pointer variable itself, in which case "no". Or are you thinking the `fixed` statement allocates memory? It does not. It just prevents the GC from moving the memory.

Comment: What is the purpose of the method? If you use ptr outside of the method then MEMORY is no longer fixed - it is only within the "fixed" block. So using ptr outsid of the method might cause problems.

Comment: thanks, i understood

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? It does nothing - `ptr` is an input parameter that gets locally modified and then thrown away. There are no externally-detectable effects of this function. If you're trying to update `ptr` (visibly to the outside), then this function is unsafe for the reason @Stefan mentioned and `ptr` would need to be the address of the pointer, not the address of an integer. (On 64-bit systems, `int*` is 64 bits, `int` is 32 bits.)